recursive query to display unit and it's children
I work with postgresql version 11
I want to display the unit and it's children
I try to use recursive query .
this is an example :
unit :
id       parentid 

UN-25    
UN-30    UN-25
UN-31    UN-25
UN-40    UN-30
UN-41    UN-30
UN-10    null
UN-255   UN-10
UN-85    UN-10

I want to display UN-25 and it's children (UN-25 , UN-30 ,UN-31 ,UN-40 , UN-41 )
I try to use this query :
select id from unit where id in (
  
   select distinct id    

   from    
   (WITH RECURSIVE tree    
   AS    
   (    
     SELECT    
         ul.name as node_name, unit.id, unit.parentid as parent_id,  
     cast(unit.id AS text) AS path,unit.status as status,unit.active as active    
      FROM unit    
     left outer join unitlang ul on ul.unit_id=unit.id and ul.lang = 'EN'   
     WHERE unit.parentid IS NULL  
     and unit.status='1'     

       UNION    
      SELECT    
          node_name, f1.id, f1.parentid,cast(tree.path || ',' || f1.id AS text) AS path,f1.status as status,f1.active as active    
      FROM    
         tree    
         JOIN unit f1 ON f1.parentid = tree.id    
        where f1.status='1'   
    )    
   SELECT id, node_name, parent_id, node_name, path FROM tree ORDER BY path) liste    
   where position('UN-25' in path)<>0 and POSITION(id in path)>=POSITION('UN-25' in path)    
  
  )

but the problem that this query display :
UN-25 , UN-30 ,UN-31 ,UN-40 , UN-41 , UN-255

the wrong result is related to this id: UN-255
and it was displayed because UN-255 contain UN-25

To avoid false matches with substrings try where position(','||'UN-25'||','  in ','||path||',')<>0          and POSITION(','||id||',' in ','||path||',')>=position(','||'UN-25'||','  in ','||path||',') (https://dbfiddle.uk/W4jSQ-m7)

What you have done seems to be more complex than the simple approach.
First select the record with id you want to match (UN-25)
Then (recursivly) select all the parents from this record. (In the first step it will find (UN-30 and UN-31, and in de second step UN-40 and UN-41)
From this result show all ids.
WITH recursive cte as (
   SELECT id, parentid 
   FROM mytable 
   WHERE id='UN-25'

   UNION ALL

   SELECT m.* 
   FROM cte c
   INNER JOIN mytable m on m.parentid = c.id 
)
SELECT id
FROM cte

see: DBFIDDLE
